# jQuery gallery with setInterval() method does not work correctly when page loses focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, gallery, setinterval

I create jQuery code for listing images every 5 sec - when the focus is on the button which is located on the picture, it must stop changing. I have a problem when my page is lost focus - when I back it dose not work correctly for some time because the coordinates of pictures are not correct!

Here is my SavasSript code:

```
var displayTimeout = 5000;
var bannerCurrentImgIndex = 0;
var timer;
var link;

function bannerDoWork() {

    var bannerImages = $("#myGallery .main_pic");
    var bannerImagesCount = bannerImages.length;

    if (bannerCurrentImgIndex == bannerImagesCount - 1) {
        bannerImages.eq(bannerCurrentImgIndex).animate({ 'left': '-725px' }, 'slow');
        bannerImages.eq(0).animate({ 'left': '0' }, 'slow');
        bannerImages.eq(bannerCurrentImgIndex - 1).css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'left': '725px' });
        bannerCurrentImgIndex = 0;
    }

    else {
        bannerImages.eq(bannerCurrentImgIndex).animate({ 'left': '-725px' }, 'slow');
        bannerImages.eq(bannerCurrentImgIndex + 1).animate({ 'left': '0' }, 'slow');
        bannerImages.eq(bannerCurrentImgIndex - 1).css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'left': '725px' });
        bannerCurrentImgIndex = bannerCurrentImgIndex + 1;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    timer = setInterval(function () { bannerDoWork(); }, displayTimeout);
    link = $("#myGallery .main_pic_btn");
    link.hover(function () { timer = clearInterval(timer); },
    function () {
        if (timer == null)
            timer = setInterval(function () { bannerDoWork(); }, displayTimeout);
    });

});
```

Comment: By "when my page is lost focus" do you mean that you've left your web browser to work on another application and then came back?

Comment: I mean that I open another tabs in browser or work on another application and then came back to that tab.

Answer (score 0):

I find answer! I set animate parameter queue=false - and now it works great! 
Example:

```
firstPic.animate({ left: 0, top: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: "slow" });
```